# Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any identity in any profile

Tags: ios

I am new in objective-c and developing an ipad application. I am creating an Adhoc build but i am getting this error: **Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any identity in any profile**
also i have deleted the old certificate and create new certificate and provisioning profile but still getting this error.

Comment: Make certain your provisioning profile is correctly set within XCode.  Open your project, select Project, Build Settings, and then the Code Signing section.  Make sure the settings are correct and try building again.

Comment: @chris still not working the problems are remain same.

Comment: @user1162034 Did you got the solution for this .... if not checkout my edited post.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you have added valid **Code Signing Identity**

Steps for this :

1) Project settings -> Properties tab --> Place your Identifier matching with your Provisional Profile.

i.e com.CompanyName.appname

2) Now, move to Build tab-->Now set the Code Signing Identity matching with your identifier.

If you are not able to get rid of this error, then revise the steps from [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Testing_Apps_on_the_iPhone_%E2%80%93_Developer_Certificates_and_Provisioning_Profiles)

Why don;t you check this forum with detail explanation from scratch : **[How to Submit Your App to Apple](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1)**

Comment: Try by deleting the certificates from Code Signing Identity & choose again.